# Is it possible to fade in radially using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a logo fade in on the page load using **jQuery**.

You can normally accomplish it on page load by just using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").fadeIn(800);
});
```

I am wondering if you could either manipulate the event `.fadeIn();` or any jQuery to have the image fade in a **circular motion**. I am trying to go for a **single circular motion**, not multiple fade in motions. I know there are ways to manipulate the linear direction of an object fading in using top, left, right, or down. I haven't found a way to make it fade in ( or fade out ) to a webpage using a circular direction.

---

In words:

1. First, the image from the angles  0 to 90 degrees will fade in, in order.
2. Next, the image from the angles 90 to 180 will fade in, in order.
3. Then, the image from the angles 180 to 270 will fade in, in order.
4. Finally, you'll be able to see the image from 270 to the full image.

If you couldn't follow the words, here is  a [visual example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8zsrj6ss8p0o7ev/circle.gif?dl=0) of what I am trying to accomplish, but **it isn't as smooth** as I am going for.

---

So far I have tried having it fade down from the top but then maybe rotate it but that wasn't what I was looking for. I'm not very knowledgeable on how to fix problems in jQuery, but I am asking **how do I accomplish this**, not specifically my code.

---

If this can't be accomplished using jQuery, then can it be accomplished using either CSS or some sort of jQuery **plugin**? If it is possible, is there a way to fade the div **out** the same way?

Comment: It can be achieved using CSS3 transitions itself. but at first show as what you have tried :)

Comment: Please post some codes that you have tried so far

Comment: @mohamedrias My code is a mix of  CSS and jQuery that doesn't work at all because I really don't know there to start. I am merely asking **how do I accomplish it** so I could then implant it into my code myself.

Comment: You can try animating a radial gradient from the background-color to transparent.

Comment: @Bram This may work but I am trying to use an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you right you can try something like this:

example:    http://jsfiddle.net/hju3dyot/

if you want it to appear more like a scroller

you can simple reduce time in the setTimeout function   [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/hju3dyot/8/)

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="img" id="left-top"></div>
    <div class="img" id="right-top"></div>
    <div class="img" id="left-bottom"></div>
    <div class="img" id="right-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
 height: 900px;
 width: 450px;
 margin: 2% auto;
 border: 1px solid #5970bb;
 border-radius: 3px;
 box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px rgba(35, 35, 35, 0.50);
 padding: 5px;
}

.img {
 background: url(http://s14.postimg.org/cdkclcbep/cat.jpg) no-repeat;
 height: 250px;
 width: 200px;
 display: inline-block;
 opacity: 0;
 -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
 -o-transition: opacity 1s;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
 transition: opacity 1s;
}

#left-top {
 background-position: -34px 0;
}

#right-top {
 background-position: -199px -10px;
}


#left-bottom {
 background-position: -25px -210px;
}

#right-bottom {
 background-position: -208px -207px;
}



.visible {
   opacity: 1;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

SCRIPT:

```
var arr = ["#left-top", "#right-top", "#right-bottom", "#left-bottom"];
var counter = 0;



$(document).ready(function () {

  function makeItVisible() {
     if (counter < arr.length) {
         $(".img").removeClass("visible");
         $(arr[counter++]).addClass("visible");
     } else {
         counter = 0;
         return;
   }
};

   setInterval(makeItVisible, 2000);
});
```

Comment: My goal is to have the object fade in so it could all be visible at once. I was going for a radial fade in as shown in the example I linked. This looks more as a slideshow and the pictures fade away. I will adjust the question accordingly.

Comment: @ShaunLoftin, my point is that you can divide your image/logo by 4 pieces and put each of them into separate div (which i did with image in my example above) and then change their opacity starting from left-top. I made another example in JSFiddle (i updated my answer with another link) and made it look like scroller .

Comment: This would work although it is fading in a **linear** direction. I am trying to ask whether you could fade in a div radially, or in a circular motion.

Comment: Liked your approach, but edited a bit to something that seems more logical (bg-position and such). Feel free to use it in your post: http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/hju3dyot/10/

Comment: Good work / idea, it definitely may be useful in everyday usage for web design .

Comment: @Bram This does work, but doesn't work for all images. Is there anyway to adjust the container size without ruining the square ratios?